# HazelcastException: CP Subsystem is not enabled

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-cloud

while doing hazelcast migration from 3.12.13 to 5.1.6 version facing issue anyone know how this could be fixed let me know.

```
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.cp.ISemaphore;

public class HazelcastSemaphore implements MetaSemaphore {

    private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    public boolean init(int permits) {

        if(semaphore == null){
            hz1.getCPSubsystem().getSemaphore(id);
            semaphore.init(permits);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Facing error

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.services.config.ConfigService]: Factory method 'configService' threw exception; nested exception is com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: CP Subsystem is not enabled!`

Comment: Have you enabled the CP subsystem? The documentation covers more information on it's configuration - https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/cp-subsystem/configuration#quickstart-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable CP subsystem.

XML sample

```
<hazelcast>
  <cp-subsystem>
   <!-- set cp-member-count with value 0 to run in unsafe mode -->
    <cp-member-count>3</cp-member-count>
    <!-- configuration options here -->
  </cp-subsystem>
</hazelcast>
```

Read more here:
https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/cp-subsystem/configuration